# Recursive stringi commands

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr, stringi

I am cleaning some string data using some `stringi` functions as part of a pipe.

I would like these functions to be recursive, so that they tackle all the possible occurrences of a re, not only the first one. I cannot predict ex ante the number of times I would need to run the function to properly clean the data.

```
library(stringi)

test_1 <- "AAA A B BBB"
str_squish(str_remove(x, "\\b[A-Z]\\b"))
result <- "AAA B BBB"
desired <- "AAA BBB"

test_2 <- "AAA AA BBB BB CCCC"
str_replace(test_2,"(?<=\\s[A-Z]{2,3})\\s","")
result <- "AAA AABBB BB CCCC"
desired <- "AAA AABBB BBCCCC"
```

Comment: For starters, try `str_remove_all`, and I think you mean `library(stringr)` and not `library(stringi)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using `gsub`, which will perform replacement of all matches:

```
test_1 <- "AAA A B BBB"
gsub(" +", " ", gsub("\\b[A-Z]\\b", "", test_1))
#[1] "AAA BBB"

test_2 <- "AAA AA BBB BB CCCC"
gsub("(?<=\\s[A-Z]{2})\\s", "", test_2, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "AAA AABBB BBCCCC"
```

For the regex `(?<=\\s[A-Z]{2,3})\\s` its not clear when the condition of 2-3 should be observed and from where you are starting: E.g. `stringr::str_replace_all` would give:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(test_2,"(?<=\\s[A-Z]{2,3})\\s","")
#[1] "AAA AABBBBBCCCC"
```

Also you can use a recursive function call:

```
f <- function(x) {
  y <- stringr::str_replace(x, "(?<=\\s[A-Z]{2,3})\\s","")
  if(x == y) x
  else f(y)
}
f(test_2)
#[1] "AAA AABBB BBCCCC"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
For the second function I split that into two, running first the 2-letters condition only and they the 3-letters condition only

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using base R's `gsub` here, which does a global regex replacement:

```r
test_1 <- "AAA A B BBB"
result <- gsub("[ ]{2,}", " ", gsub("[ ]*\\b[A-Z]\\b[ ]*", " ", test_1))
result

[1] "AAA BBB"
```